# Modifying vertical LinearLayoutManager so it can also be scrolled horizontally (video included)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to modify the vertical  **LinearLayoutManager** which I use with a **RecyclerView** so it can be scrolled horizontally.

When the RecyclerView is scrolled vertically it adds new items because I’m extending *LinearLayoutManager*.

I thought this will solve the problem.

```
public class CustomLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {


    public TableLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollHorizontally() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int scrollHorizontallyBy(int dx, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int delta = -dx;

        offsetChildrenHorizontal(delta);

        return -delta;
    }

}
```

Now when I scroll the RecyclerView horizonatlly it works but the content can be scrolled offscreen.
Also when the content is scrolled horizontally and then I scroll vertically, the RecycerView will add the new views aligned with left screen border and not with initial views.

Video that demonstrates the behaviour:
http://youtu.be/FbuZ_jph7pw 
What I'm doing wrong ?

**UPDATE**
(as suggested by @yigit)

Now I'm using the modified version of *LinearLayoutManager* (I'm not extending it anymore because I need to add offset to RecyclerView children in private method **fill(....)**).

These are the changes I made:

```
    private int childrenLeftOffset = 0;
    private int childrenMaxWith = 800;  // I must update this value with children max width
    @Override
    public int scrollHorizontallyBy(int dx, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {

        int delta = -dx;
        int newOffset = childrenLeftOffset + delta;
        if (newOffset < 0) {
            if(newOffset < -childrenMaxWith) {
                //right edge reached
                offsetChildrenHorizontal(-(childrenMaxWith - Math.abs(childrenLeftOffset)));
                childrenLeftOffset  = -childrenMaxWith;
                delta = 0;  // RecyclerView will draw right edge effect.
            } else {
                //scroll horizontally
                childrenLeftOffset  = childrenLeftOffset + delta;
                offsetChildrenHorizontal(delta);
            }
        } else {
            //left edge reached
            offsetChildrenHorizontal(Math.abs(childrenLeftOffset));
            childrenLeftOffset  = 0;
            delta = 0; // RecyclerView will draw left edge effect.
        }

        return -delta;
    }

    private int fill(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RenderState renderState, RecyclerView.State state, boolean stopOnFocusable) {
            ........
            ........

            left = left + myLeftOffset;
            layoutDecorated(view, left + params.leftMargin, top + params.topMargin, right - params.rightMargin, bottom - params.bottomMargin);

            .......
            .......
    }
```

Scrolling CustomLinearLayout (updated video) http://youtu.be/DHeXkvpgruo

The problem now is to get the maximum width of RecyclerView children and update childrenMaxWith.

Comment: Hey @VovaHost i'm in a similar kind of problem can you help me out

Comment: Hey @VovaHost can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952965/recyclerview-horizontal-scrolling-to-left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LinearLayoutManager does supports scrolling in one direction so when it needs to layout a new child, it simply starts from left.
`offsetChildren` method just moves children, does not keep any information.

You are better off cloning LinearLayoutManager and overriding `layoutChunk` method. But you'll need to do it every time a new RV version is released.

Another possible (quick & dirty) solution is:

- Keep track of your horizontal scroll position
- override `layoutDecorated` in your LayoutManager and offset `left` and `right` values by your horizontal scroll offset, then call super.

This will probably work but has the potential of breaking in any future change in LayoutManger. It is not high risk though because that method is pretty core.

Comment: I can't find layoutChunk method. I have some troubles implementing the second solution you suggested. I updated the code.

Comment: You need a custom solution for `childrenMaxWith` as RV cannot possibly know it.  Probably your better option is to calculate and cache it every time you need that value. And you can do it only for visible items.

Comment: I'm trying now to get the RecyclerView width after it has been measured.
I will post here the answer if it works.

Comment: Still curious what was `layoutChunk` about.

Comment: @vovahost if you're curious about `layoutChunk`, check out the sources of `GridLayoutManager`

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar problem with displaying tabular data in a RecyclerView. In my case, all of the views being recycled had the same width. I know that's not the case with the original question, but going with a uniform width ensures that your columns are all aligned properly, so it's easier to read that way. It also makes it much easier to determine when to stop scrolling horizontally; you just use `getChildAt(0)?.measuredWidth`. Also, the API might have changed since 2015 within LinearLayoutManager: I found that you have to override `layoutDecoratedWithMargins` instead of `layoutDecorated` if you want to use the "quick and dirty" solution suggested by yigit (it probably doesn't hurt to override both). This is how I implemented it:

```
class MyRowLayoutManager(context: Context) : LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false) {

    private var horizontalOffset = 0

    override fun canScrollHorizontally(): Boolean = true

    override fun scrollHorizontallyBy(dx: Int, recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler?, state: RecyclerView.State?): Int {
        if (childCount == 0) return 0

        val rowWidth = getChildAt(0)?.measuredWidth ?: return 0

        // if the row is narrower than the RecyclerView's width, don't scroll
        if (rowWidth <= width) return 0

        val remainingPxRight = rowWidth - width - horizontalOffset
        // cut scrolling short if we're about to reach end of the row
        val scrolled = when {
            dx > remainingPxRight -> remainingPxRight
            dx < -horizontalOffset -> -horizontalOffset
            else -> dx
        }

        horizontalOffset += scrolled
        offsetChildrenHorizontal(-scrolled)
        return scrolled
    }

    override fun layoutDecorated(child: View, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {
        super.layoutDecorated(child, left - horizontalOffset, top, right - horizontalOffset, bottom)
    }

    override fun layoutDecoratedWithMargins(child: View, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {
        super.layoutDecoratedWithMargins(child, left - horizontalOffset, top, right - horizontalOffset, bottom)
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG. This works great. If your child has dynamic width. Just make the child width `wrap_content`.