# ViewPager page scaling issue with page transformer

Tags: java, android, user-interface, animation

Hi I'm developing an app where I'm using `viewpager` to make custom animation with `viewpager` transformer but the problem is that there is scaling issue with `viewpager` page transformer. I tried every possible x and y scaling but still the problem is the same. I'm having hard time understanding the problem please if someone can help me out here.

Below is the image of what I'm trying to achieve

**Update:**

Well looks I did not find the solution yet but still trying to figure as I'm almost there with just left with the designing of cardstack look.

[image: My expected output]

My page Transformation code

```
public class CardStackTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
    private static final float DEFAULT_CURRENT_PAGE_SCALE = 1.0f;
    private static final float OTHER_PAGE_SCALE = 0.9f;
    private int dimen;

    @Override
    public void transformPage(@NonNull View view, float position) {

        //view.setScaleX(DEFAULT_CURRENT_PAGE_SCALE);
        // view.setScaleY(DEFAULT_CURRENT_PAGE_SCALE);
        /*dimen = view.getWidth();
        int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
        final float translateValue = position * -pageWidth;
        if (translateValue < -pageWidth) {
            view.setTranslationX(translateValue);
        }

        if (position < -1) {
            view.setAlpha(0);

        } else if (position <= 0) {
            view.setAlpha(1.0f);
            view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);
            view.setTranslationY(0);
            view.setScaleX(1);
            view.setScaleY(1);
        } else if (position <= 1) {
            view.setTranslationX(dimen * position);
            view.setAlpha(-0.5f * position + 1.0f);
            //  view.setTranslationX((-dimen / 1.1F) * position);
            view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);
            view.setTranslationY((dimen / 200.09f) * position);

            float scaleFactor = OTHER_PAGE_SCALE
                    + (1 - OTHER_PAGE_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
            view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
            view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);
            //view.setScaleX(OTHER_PAGE_SCALE);
            //view.setScaleY(OTHER_PAGE_SCALE);
        } else {
            view.setAlpha(0);
        }*/
        view.setScaleX(DEFAULT_CURRENT_PAGE_SCALE);
        view.setScaleY(DEFAULT_CURRENT_PAGE_SCALE);
        dimen = view.getWidth();

        if(position < -1) {
            view.setAlpha(0);

        } else if(position <= 0) {
            view.setAlpha(1.0f);
            view.setTranslationX(0);
            view.setTranslationY(0);
            view.setScaleX(DEFAULT_CURRENT_PAGE_SCALE);
            view.setScaleY(OTHER_PAGE_SCALE);
        } else if(position <= 1) {
            final float scaleFactor = OTHER_PAGE_SCALE + (1 - OTHER_PAGE_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));

           // view.setTranslationX(dimen * -position);
            view.setAlpha(-0.5f * position + 1.0f);
            view.setTranslationX((-dimen / 1.1F) * position);
            view.setTranslationY((dimen / 209.9f)*position);
            view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);
            view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
            view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);
        } else {
            view.setAlpha(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: the problem is i'm not getting the output as shown in pic i have been trying for days now

Comment: post the picture as it is now

Comment: i'm trying every thing i could to achieve it

Comment: @Eminem please see this my current output https://imgur.com/a/3smfXKq

Comment: So @Eminem can you help me out

Comment: but what is with the toolbar??

Comment: the tablayout, Explore it isn't in your picture..

Comment: that is because i can add toolbar anytime but my main concern is horizontal xcardstack at the moment

Comment: try adding that see if that fixes your problem

Comment: toolbar isnt fixing the problem

Comment: and toolbar and viewpager are not at all related

Comment: I said tablayout, not toolbar.what is explore and three dots aren't those a tablayout?

Comment: no that is a toolbar not a tablayout with a textview and imageview

Comment: Could you check `TranslationX`, `TranslationY`,`ScaleX`,`ScaleY` in each view **in the end** of function `transformPage()`? I'm afraid the complex computing makes some values greater than 1.

Comment: Considering safety, the `transformPage()` will calculate every frame while position changing, be sure to change ScaleX, ScaleY only once?

Comment: so @sakiM what changes should i make can you guide me here i'm not able to do it.please could you help me.

Comment: Simply check is hard code a fixed factor to all `setScaleY`, like `0.6`. But I suggest log the value of `TranslationX, TranslationY,ScaleX,ScaleY` in the end of `transformPage()` first. Then add Log to each `if-else` branch to check whether assigning these in a wrong condition.

Comment: I tried setting ScaleY to lower values i get one card at stack but the problem is when i scroll the back card pops up instead of smotth scroll this is the point where it doesnt have smooth scroll

Comment: Please @SakiM could you help me out because i'm stuck at it for weeks now and it is really important for me to do it.Please i request you.

Comment: @Smith debug your app to see the values it returns

Comment: `where it doesnt have smooth scroll` sounds like your transform-function is not continuous. Be sure this function is continuous: `f(position) -> ScaleY` in `position=(0,1,-1)`.

Comment: I calculate the values for the current transform-function, seems `scaleFactor` always a negative-number when position belong to (0,1)? Please log `scaleFactor` and `position` in run-time.

Comment: ok can you tell me  more about it

Answer (score 0):

check below code

```
import android.view.View
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
import kotlin.math.abs

class SliderTransformer() : ViewPager.PageTransformer {

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "SliderTransformer"

        private const val DEFAULT_TRANSLATION_X = .50f
        private const val DEFAULT_TRANSLATION_FACTOR = 1.2f

        private const val SCALE_FACTOR = .14f
        private const val DEFAULT_SCALE = 1f

        private const val ALPHA_FACTOR = .3f
        private const val DEFAULT_ALPHA = 1f

    }

    override fun transformPage(page: View, position: Float) {

        page.apply {

            ViewCompat.setElevation(page, -abs(position))

            val scaleFactor = -SCALE_FACTOR * position + DEFAULT_SCALE
            val alphaFactor = -ALPHA_FACTOR * position + DEFAULT_ALPHA

            when {
                position <= 0f -> {
                    translationX = DEFAULT_TRANSLATION_X
                    scaleX = DEFAULT_SCALE
                    scaleY = DEFAULT_SCALE
                    alpha = DEFAULT_ALPHA + position
                }
                position >0 -> {
                    scaleX = scaleFactor
                    scaleY = scaleFactor
                    translationX = -(width / DEFAULT_TRANSLATION_FACTOR) * position
                    alpha = alphaFactor
                }
                else -> {
                    translationX = DEFAULT_TRANSLATION_X
                    scaleX = DEFAULT_SCALE
                    scaleY = DEFAULT_SCALE
                    alpha = DEFAULT_ALPHA
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```