# Toolbar overlapping recyclerview

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app where I'm using recyclerview along with toolbar to my surprise toolbar is overlapping recyclerview even though I have used coordinator layout maybe I'm wrong in implementing it properly so here it is.

xml

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    <!-- AppBarLayout is a wrapper for a Toolbar in order to apply scrolling effects. -->
    <!-- Note that AppBarLayout expects to be the first child nested within a CoordinatorLayout -->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <!-- Toolbar is the actual app bar with text and the action items -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/White"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">
            <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pulse"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context="com.ct.listrtrial.fragments.FeedFragment">


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/feed_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="9"

                android:paddingTop="15dp">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `NestedScrollView` that contains the `RecyclerView` should have the attribute `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`.

This will inform the `CoordinatorLayout` that the `NestedScrollView` needs to lay itself out in coordination with the app bar.

Comment: i added the app layout_behaviour still it is same

Comment: I would also remove the layout weight on the `RecyclerView` and remove the `LinearLayout`. As is, those won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/main_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

<!-- AppBarLayout is a wrapper for a Toolbar in order to apply scrolling effects. -->
<!-- Note that AppBarLayout expects to be the first child nested within a CoordinatorLayout -->
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

    <!-- Toolbar is the actual app bar with text and the action items -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/White"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">
        <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pulse"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.ct.listrtrial.fragments.FeedFragment">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/feed_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="9"

            android:paddingTop="15dp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: ohh no this one line was bugging me and even Tanis 7x suggested me the same still is missed out..

Comment: hey can i get some help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50390243/viewpager-page-scaling-issue-with-page-transformer