# Changing a value of an item in ArrayList (copied) also changed the value of item in main ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I have an ArrayList in which I am adding some items.

```
    private List<Product> mMainList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Product> mCopyList;

    mMainList.add(new Product(true,"First"));
    mMainList.add(new Product(true,"Second"));
    mMainList.add(new Product(true,"Third"));
```

Now I have a new list `mCopyList` to which I am initialising with `mMainList`

```
mCopyList = new ArrayList<>(mMainList);
```

Now I am changing the name of a product of 0th index in `mCopyList`

```
mCopyList.get(0).setName("First After Change");
```

**Problem**

The problem I am facing is, mMainList is getting changed automatically. I don't want to change mMainList. Please suggest. Thank You.

Comment: You copy the List  right, but the reference to the elements is the same. So you have to do a deep copy.

Comment: While adding data into `mCopyList ` using object cloning technique, means by set data by using `getter()` and `setter()` and then add your data into `mCopyList `. By using this technique you will not face this issue.

Comment: @SwapnilKshirsagar it doesn't work. I tried ` mCopyList = new ArrayList<>(mMainList);

        Product product = mCopyList.get(0);
        product.setName("First After Change");
        product.setActive(false);`

Comment: @AshishTiwari An example is in the link to the duplicate

Comment: @Jens got it. thank you. I was thinking addAll() and new operator can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clone of main arraylist like this

```
private List<Product> mMainList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Product> mCopyList;

    mMainList.add(new Product(true,"First"));
    mMainList.add(new Product(true,"Second"));
    mMainList.add(new Product(true,"Third"));
```

now clone of arraylist

```
mCopyList= (ArrayList<>)mMainList.clone();
```

now change is clone list

```
mCopyList.get(0).setName("First After Change");
```

this will not affect your main list.
hope it will help you!!

Comment: Thanks Hemant. but it says "clone has protected access in java.lang.Object

Comment: hello @Hemant Parmar can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952965/recyclerview-horizontal-scrolling-to-left?rq=1

Comment: Try this when you change the value of mCopyList:  mCopyList.set(0,"First After Change");                                                            This would not change the value of mMainList.