# In SQLite database insertWithOnConflict is not working in android application

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

In my sqlite database I used insertWithOnConflict  method in application for ignore duplicate data entry in my sqlite database inn android application. But some how I don't know it's not working in my code. If any one have solution regarding this issue so help me.

Here below my code.

```
 public void AddPattern(Pattern_Model pattern_model) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    //values.put("id",pattern_model.getId());
    values.put("pattern_name", pattern_model.getPattern_name());
    values.put("value", pattern_model.getPattern_value());

   long ln= db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_NAME, "pattern_name",values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);

    //db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
    if(ln != -1){
        Log.d("replace", "ok");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `CONFLICT_REPLACE` for your requirement,

```
long ln= db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_NAME, BaseColumns._ID,values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```

Comment: can you help me as well with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952965/recyclerview-horizontal-scrolling-to-left

Comment: Thanks for your responce. I have changed CONFLICT_IGNORE to CONFLICT_REPLACE but still not working.

Comment: data is added in my database, not replace. I want to change value every time for the same pattern_name but can't do so. "value" and "pattern_name" are my columns.

Comment: You can use BaseColumns._ID

Comment: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase&method=insertWithOnConflict