# Best performans for same URL, different images with Glide V4

Tags: android, android-glide

In my app I am getting image from my server into Imageview. I using this code:

```
 try {
            GlideApp.with(mContext)
                    .load(myCard.url)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.no_connection)
                    .apply(new RequestOptions().centerCrop())
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                    .skipMemoryCache(true)
                    .into(arkafon);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

it works but each time app download images as a new one so internet usage increasing. is that posibble to check if image is changed, app should download new one. otherwise if there is NO change at image app should use downloaded before image.

Comment: it was working or not ?

Comment: maybe this can help? https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1847

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks ugly but this is my solution

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(new Date());
        try {
            GlideApp.with(mContext)
                    .load(myCard.url)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.no_connection)
                    .apply(new RequestOptions().centerCrop())
                    .signature(new ObjectKey(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH))))
                    .into(arkafon);
        } catch (Exception e) { 
        }
```

it will update all images monthly, if you want earlier you can use Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR

Answer (score 3):

If you want load new image with same name as previously loaded file than you must have one field which will define image uniqueness.
I am giving you a example for it : suppose you have profile image with url , so you need one more flag which tell's us about last updated date and time
if you have that uniqueness than you can load image on basis of it by below code. **In below example i have lastModified is unique fields.**

```
Glide.with(this)
        .load(avatarFile)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
        .signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(avatarFile.lastModified())))
        .into(ivProfile);
```

Comment: Hey @Rujul Gandhi can you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952965/recyclerview-horizontal-scrolling-to-left

Comment: Nope, it is getting same image even if I change image with newone at server

Comment: You have to make it rename first from server as well.

Comment: but if renamed the image, URL will change. I dont want to change url

Comment: Actually Glide will get the image from cache and cache has unique identity as name. so if you will not change the name then it will take image from cache.

Comment: Do you have some unique field that gives you that image's identity ?

Comment: Just let me know if you have some unique field or some uniqueness for it. I will guide you about it

Comment: I have updated the answer so please check the answer , I have tried and its working for me

Answer (score 0):

I also face this problem, and finally I find this issue, to solve the problem. Refer to this [Glide issue](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/527#issuecomment-317515373)

My code is like this. And the DataSave is a util class for SharedPreferences.

```
String oldSignature = DataSave.readData(signatureKey);
String newSignature = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
DataSave.saveData(signatureKey, newSignature);

Glide.with(context)
        .load(glideUrl)
        .thumbnail(Glide.with(context)
                .load(glideUrl)
                .signature(new ObjectKey(oldSignature)))
        .signature(new ObjectKey(newSignature))
        .placeholder(placeHolder)
        .error(placeHolder)
        .listener(listener)
        .into(imageView);
```