# Volley Post with JSON - getting 422 Status Code

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley, loopbackjs

I am trying to use [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/) to send a JSON object to a Loopback application API which is using MongoDB. I can see that the data is being saved in the database successfully. But the Volley response always shows that the status code is [422](https://restpatterns.mindtouch.us/HTTP_Status_Codes/422_-_Unprocessable_Entity). Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

This is the error message:

`BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 422 for http://localhost:3001/api/Persons`

This is the JSON I am trying to send:

```
{
  "map_coordinates": {
    "lat": xxxxxx,
    "lng": xxxxxxx
  },
  "first_name": "xxxxx",
  "middle_name": "",
  "family_name": "xxxxxx",
  "gender": "xxxxxx",
  "role": "xxxxxx",
  "dob": "2017-09-28T05:51:40.836Z",
  "picture_of_person": "",
  "username": "ajxxxx7@gmail.com",
  "deviceToken": "xxxxxxxx",
  "portal_address": "xxxxx",
  "email": "ajxxxxx7@gmail.com",
  "password": "xxxxxxx",
  "vcode": 562991,
  "mobile": "+91xxxxxxxx"
}
```

I do not think that there is a problem with the JSON because, if I POST the same object from the Loopback explorer then the request goes through successfully and returns status code 200.

This is the code I am using to send the JSON request.

```
public void postJsonRequest(String url, JSONObject data, final Callback<JSONObject, VolleyError> callback) {
    JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, data, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            callback.onSuccess(response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            callback.onFailure(error);
        }
    });
    makeJsonRequest(objectRequest);
}

private void makeJsonRequest(JsonObjectRequest request) {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(EngageMyTime.getInstance().getEMTContext());
    queue.add(request);
}
```

Any help/idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey Ajil O can you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952965/recyclerview-horizontal-scrolling-to-left

Comment: @Smith Will have a look in a while

Comment: what is the error message on the loopback side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the default charset UTF-8 on server side and encode in UTF-8 the json data before send

In android with

```
URLEncoder.encode(string,"UTF-8");
```

Comment: I have done that. I think it might be some problem with Google's Volley. The request goes through with Okhttp

Answer (score 0):

What format are you used in response? İf you can't use JSON,You may see this error. Because postJSONResponse use JSONObject in parsing. Something like this. You can write custom request or change your response type to JSON.
Example of custom request is:

```
public class SignUpRequest extends Request<String> {
    private Map<String, String> mParams;
    public SignUpRequest(String url, Response.ErrorListener listener) {
        super(url, listener);
    }

    public SignUpRequest(int method, String url,String email,String userName,String password, Response.ErrorListener listener) {
        super(method, url, listener);
        mParams=new HashMap<>();
        mParams.put("username",userName);
        mParams.put("email",email);
        mParams.put("password",password);
    }




    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(String response) {
        Log.e("Response",response);
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

        return mParams;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        String data=new String(response.data);
        return Response.success(data+" "+response.statusCode,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    }
}
```